# editButtonItem title resets to default when Done

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` in which I have `UITableView` and I'm using `editButtonItem` for editing the `UITableView`.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.editButtonItem.title = @"تحرير";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

On first launch the the title for edit button is shown as desired. But when I tap on it, the Table view enters editing mode and `Done` is shown. When I tap on `Done`, the title resets to default `Edit`.

Do I have to set the title on every toggle in:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Or is there any better way to do it? I also want to change the "Done" text while in editing mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes ,
If you want custom titles you have to do it in

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 0):

take one `UIBarButtonItem` like bellow in .h file..

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnSave;
```

after that in .m file

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    btnSave = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    btnSave.target = self;
    btnSave.action = @selector(btnEdit_Click:);
    btnSave.title = @"Edit";// here give title which you want...
    self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSave;
}

-(IBAction)btnEdit_Click:(id)sender
{
        if ([btnSave.title isEqualToString:@"Edit"]) {
              ///something do here and also change the title of button here
             [btnSave setTitle:@"Save"];// just for an example

        }
        else {
              ///something do here and also change the title of button here
              [btnSave setTitle:@"Edit"];//just for an example
        }
}
```

i hope this help you...

:)